# SwiftUI: How to update image to filled / outlined in TabView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I'm trying to use filled image when it is selected and outlined image when it is deselected. I tried to render the images but still filled

So I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```swift
struct ListTabView: View {

    @State private var selectedTab = 0

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {

                Text("Tab 1")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedTab += 1
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        selectedTab == 0 ? Image(systemName: "star.fill") : Image(systemName: "star")
                        Text("First")
                    }
                    .tag(0)

                Text("Tab 2")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedTab -= 1
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        selectedTab == 1 ? Image(systemName: "moon.stars.fill") : Image(systemName: "moon.stars")
                        Text("Second")
                    }
                    .tag(1)
            }
            .accentColor(.pink)
            .onAppear {
                UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListTabView()
    }
}
```

[image: The second item in Tab View is filled and should be outlined]

Comment: At first glance I thought it was a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57140435/1746142 But no, you have a different problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually works. The issue is something else not documented that I can find. If you use a non `.fill` variant of an SF Font, the `.fill` variant will be substituted. Use the following code to test it:

```
TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
    VStack {
        Text("Tab 1")
        Text(Image(systemName: "star"))
    }
    .tabItem {
        selectedTab == 0 ? Image(systemName: "star") : Image(systemName: "sun.max")
        Text("First")
    }
    .tag(0)
    
    VStack {
        Text("Tab 2")
        Text(Image(systemName: "moon.stars"))
    }
    .tabItem {
        selectedTab == 1 ? Image(systemName: "moon.stars") : Image(systemName: "sun.max")
        Text("Second")
    }
    .tag(1)
}
```

You will note I used plain variants, and yet the filled variant was used. Also, you don't need the `.onTap()`, but I suspect you added it when the images didn't seem to switch.

Comment: You're absolutely right because I had a doubt when I tried to use different symbol to see if the selection is actually work. @Yrb Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'll use onTap() to switch between tabs in code. @Yrb

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to Image / Label:

```swift
Image(systemName: selectedTab == 0 ? "star.fill" : "star")
.environment(\.symbolVariants, selectedTabItemIndex == 0 ? .fill : .none)
```

It will allow you to set the symbol variants as you would expect it.

Answer (score 1):

In case your app supports iOS 14 and you can't use `.symbolVariants` environment, this hack will save you:

```
Image(uiImage: 
    UIImage(systemName: selectedTab == 0 ? "star.fill" : "star")
)
```

This bypasses Apple hidden logic that replace all plain icons with filled in a tab bar.